# Fluid DIVS on HTML / CSS Layout

Tags: css, html, fluid-layout

This is the first time i'm trying to create a custom html page from scratch and I'm having some trouble :

This is what i want basically:

[image]

I want the site to automatically resize according to the window size - the first div bg should be full width and its inside should be fixed width (centered)

I first tried creating each divs manually - seems ok so far except the inside div inside the header i want to center

I'm really noob in css/html , so if there is any way to improve my code - please let me know

I tried several ways but keep getting stuck .

Tried:

- [MaxDesign Article](http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/)
- [LayZilla](http://layzilla.com)
- [CSS-Tricks Fluid](http://css-tricks.com/the-perfect-fluid-width-layout/)

I was using the above as examples , but i kept getting stuck so i decided to start from zero

### CSS

```
#body_wrapper {
    width:100%;
    background:white;
}
#header {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
}
#header_inside {
    width:500px;
    height:180px;
    background:green;
}
#content {
    width:100%;
    height:600px;
    background:blue;
}
#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    background:yellow;
}
```

### HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="body_wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="header_inside"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you want ::

http://jsfiddle.net/rahulrulez/b4gWx/

Just add following properties to inner divs.. I have followed HTML5 convention and I recommend you to do so.

```
width:500px;
margin:0 auto;
```

After getting familiar with HTML and CSS enough.. I recommend you to kick start development with frameworks like Twitter Bootstrap or Zurb Foundation

Answer (score 1):

To center a div, use: `margin:auto;`. So;

```
#header_inside {
   margin: auto;
   [ ... ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change  the css for header like this:

```
#header {
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 10px 0;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background: red;
}
#header_inside {
margin: 0px auto;
width: 500px;
height: 180px;
background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If responsive and resizing is your priorty try Twitter Bootstrap Css . 
It works great for responsive features with the help of predefined classes itself.

Comment: Thanks A Lot Guys  - Been really helpful - Once i get 10 rep , i'll vote up evryone

Answer (score 0):

The `margin: auto` solution should work.

You can also use text-align:

```
.outerDiv {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.innerDiv {
    width: 500px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <div id="menuitems"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="contents"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="footers"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:1000px;
}
body {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:1000px
}
#header {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    display:block;
}
#logo {
    width:50%;
    margin:5px auto;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
}
#menu {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    display:block;
}
#menuitems {
    width:50%;
    margin:5px auto;
    border:1px solid blue;
    height:15px;
    display:block;
}

#content {
    width:100%;
    height:800px;
    border:1px solid green;
    display:block;
}
#contents {
    width:50%;
    margin:15px auto;
    border:1px solid green;
    height:650px;
    display:block;
}

#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    border:1px solid orange;
    display:block;
}
#footers {
    width:50%;
    margin:5px auto;
    border:1px solid orange;
    height:40px;
    display:block;
}
```

## <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c47yA/20/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

**Html**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

    header,nav,section,footer{
    width:960px
    margin:0 auto
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <nav>
        <u1>
                <li>list items</li>
        <ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
<section>
    <article>your content follows here</article>
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```